# How can I destroy/remove an instance of a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery

I'm using sidr, a jQuery plugin for sliding in side menus. It offers a couple of public methods, and I want to extend it with a "destroy" method, which would remove the instance of the plugin.

I want to be able to call `$.sidr('destroy', mySidrInstance)` just as I already can call `$.sidr('open', mySidrInstance)`

Here are the public methods

```
    // Sidr public methods
var methods = {
    open: function(name, callback) {
        privateMethods.execute('open', name, callback);
    },
    close: function(name, callback) {
        privateMethods.execute('close', name, callback);
    },
    toggle: function(name, callback) {
        privateMethods.execute('toggle', name, callback);
    },
    destroy: function() {
        // I want to create this. What should I write here?
    }
};

$.sidr = function( method ) {

    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    }
    else if ( typeof method === 'function' || typeof method === 'string' || ! method ) {
        return methods.toggle.apply( this, arguments );
    }
    else {
        $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.sidr' );
    }

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should clean up and revert to the state before your plugin was activated.

If you've added elements with bound event handlers, you can simple call [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) on them, since this will remove them from the DOM and remove all bound events and data.